# How can I convert a column with values like [1] (objects) to a numeric value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric

I want to convert the following column (part of a DataFrame) into a numeric value.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Cluster": [[0], [1], [0], [2]]})
```

My following code didn't work:

```py
pd['Cluster_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Cluster'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Try `df['Cluster_numeric'] = df['Cluster'].str[0]`

Comment: Could be there more than one int in the list?

Comment: no there is just one per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work considering your length of the list is always 1

```
df['Cluster_numeric']=df['Cluster'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: `int` is not required here you can select the first element.

Comment: `df['Culster'].explode()` would be much more generic.

Comment: df['Culster'].explode()  is also a object